# Is it a good idea to cite my own unpublished paper in another paper, an extension of the unpublished paper?

Tags: publications, mathematics, paper-submission, extended-paper

I have submitted a research paper in mathematics to a journal and also uploaded it to Arxiv. Another paper I have written is an extension of this yet unpublished paper. So in the second paper, I have to mention or cite the first. Since the previous paper is yet not published, I have only one option: cite it from the Arxiv link. But I am thinking that citing a paper that is in Arxiv (submitted to a journal and yet not published), will be less appealing to reviewers.

So the question: Is it a good idea to cite my own unpublished paper to another paper, extension of the previous paper ?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/162537/how-to-address-dependencies-when-publishing-a-chain-of-papers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you don't really have an option. You need to cite your early work that is published in any form to avoid charges of self-plagiarism.

Cite what can be seen. Your submission of the new paper will take long enough that you will have an option to update the citation if the older paper is *more formally* published.

Reviewers understand these things. They see it, they do it. Don't be concerned.

Comment: Small addition: In your citation it could be useful to add that the paper is actually under submission as well, just to show it's not only uploaded to arXiv.

Comment: @Jeroen, I doubt that is necessary. But it, too, can be edited out at some future point. Any initial submission _will_ be changed in some ways. Time is on the author's side here.