# Is it accepted that I submit two novel papers at the same time, but one uses the methods in the other one?

Tags: publications, phd, citations, paper-submission, stem

I have written two STEM papers (Paper1 and Paper2) and I have already submitted Paper1. Paper2 implements some of the methods presented in Paper1. The conference I submitted for Paper1 and the journal considered for Paper2 both require novel work and state that the work presented in the paper is not published or under review by other journals. Both the conference and the journal are prestigious and Q1.

Paper2 is more of an expansion of the first with more methods, data and discussion. So, what are my options for Paper2 now? I am thinking of one of those:

1- Rewrite the methods of the first paper but with different phrasing than what was shown in the first paper. I think this falls under "Not under review by other journals".

2- Option1 but without mentioning that the method is novel and try to make the writing as short as possible so Paper1 is the complete version.

3- Wait for the first paper to be published then reference it and summarize the methods. The problem with this option is that the conference will be in October and the paper will be published in Decemeber, and I cannot afford to wait ~9 months.

Is there an option I am missing?

Comment: Appendix. Put whatever is in paper1 in a very short form in the appendix of paper2. Then if you are lucky, during peer review you will have the possibility to add the freshly published paper1 in paper2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to address dependencies when publishing a chain of papers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/162537/how-to-address-dependencies-when-publishing-a-chain-of-papers)

Comment: Just a thought; why do you submit these papers at the same time? Can't you postpone one of them to submit after the other is accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is totally acceptable. But you are missing at least one option, and that is the one that I think is prefarable:

Submit the second paper, and cite paper 1 as "submitted" (add the title and authors, but not the journal/conference). It is often possible to add information that is intended "for review only": it will be sent to the reviewers but not published. The essential information from paper 1 can be added in this way for the reviewers to understand paper 2.

This can lead to 2 situations:

- Paper 1 is published first, and the citation in paper 2 can be updated before it is published
- Paper 2 is published first, and the citation remains incomplete. This is not ideal, but I have seen it regularly so apparently it is acceptable by some journals. Readers will be able to find the first paper based on the list of authors and title.